# How to fix "[Errno 111] Connection refused" error in Python while connecting to mongoDb from remote linux server

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, remote-server

I have a remote Linux server setup where I am hosting a python script. The requirement is to connect to MongoDB that is hosted in a local windows machine. I understand that we can't directly access MongoDB as it allows only `localhost:27017` by default.

Tried updating the `mongo.cfg` file by changing the properties under "net". However this didn't help. Can someone help me out in this case. I am getting the error below:

> 10.30.118.230:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

This is the code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://{username}:{password}@{windows_system_ip_whereMongoDb_is_hosted}/{dbname}")
db = client.{dbname}
try: 
    db.command("serverStatus")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("You are connected!")
client.close()
```

Comment: Is your script on the same server as MongoDB?

Comment: No. MongoDB is in my local machine which is a windows machine. And the script is hosted in a remote linux server

Answer (score 0):

BY default windows firewall block all input connections in port 27017, you should enable the port 27017 in windows firewall to allow the connections through the port.

[Configure Windows netsh Firewall for MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-windows-netsh-firewall/)

Comment: Can see so many commands there in above document. May I know which one in specific is applicable for my case.